# upload image in database in php with title name into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

i want to upload image in database in php with title name ...
like this :: (domain.com/image-ID-title.jpg) -- (domain.com/shd64ht-this-is-my-first-post.jpg)

this is my code and the output is (domain.com/image-ID.jpg) -- (domain.com/shhk87y.jpg)

```
function store_file($file){
    $ext = explode('.', $file['name']);     
    $ext = $ext[count($ext)-1];

    do {
        $file_name = genfilename($ext);
    } while(file_exists("../img/{$file_name}"));

    move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], "../img/{$file_name}");
    return $file_name;
}

function genfilename($ext){
    $a = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9");
    $nm = "";
    for($i=1; $i<=8; $i++){
        $nm = $nm . $a[rand(0,35)];
    }
    return $nm . ".{$ext}";
}

if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
    $title_save = $_POST['title'];
    $pic = $_FILES['pic'];

    $pic_name = store_file($pic);

    mysql_query("insert my_posts SET title ='$title_save' ,pic ='$pic_name'") or die(mysql_error());
    $flg_okay = 0;
    $flg_okay = 1;
}
```

Comment: `$_FILES['pic']['name'];`

Comment: please please do not use `mysql_*` functions. its 2018. Also this code isn't in production yet right?

Comment: Why are you using the long-deprecated `mysql_` code library? It was discontinued many years ago and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written using this library. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as possible, and then learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data from malicious input. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Comment: And then find a tutorial showing you how to deal with file uploads, there are many. It will explain how to access the right parts of the $_FILES array to get what you need

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand fully what you intend, but I wouldn't advise storing images in the database. What I think you should do is receive an image and store it's information on a table. Something among the lines of:

(using HTTPPost or Put to submit the file, according to whatever validations you'd want)

```
| id | name           | alias     | path                           | created_at | updated_at |
+----+----------------+-----------+--------------------------------+------------+------------+
|  1 | filestored.jpg | mypicture | path/to/image/withoutimagename | timestamp  | timestamp  |
```

and retrieving it by using an ID (whatever you feel its appropriate) returning path+name. This path+name can be a url or you can just tell it download a certain file based on http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php